# Basic nginx URL rewriting issue

Tags: nginx

I'm completely new to nginx and I was wondering if someone could give me a hand.

What I'm trying to to is turn this:

domain.com/ngu/short.php?t=123

into

domain.com/t/123

If someone could explain to me how it's done, I would be very grateful. I have looked around the site for a similar situation, but I haven't found anything exactly the same so I'm having some difficulty. Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 0):

the following location block does the rewrite:

```
location ~ /ngu/short.php {
  if ($args_t) {
    rewrite ^ http://$host/t/$v? last;
  }
}
```

but that requires you enumerate all possible arguments, if you have lots of potential arguments it's probably easier to do

```
location ~ /ngu/short.php {
  if ($args ~ "([a-z]+)=(\d+)") {
    set $p $1;
    set $v $2;
    rewrite ^ http://$host/$p/$v? last;
  }
}
```

explanation:

- we do a location that matches on the /ngu/short.php path
- the first code block above checks if we have a t=value argument and if so does the rewrite
- the second code block above checks for a more general argument=something. We then need to save the backreferences in variables because a rewrite rule resets the backreferences which prevents using them directly
- in either case if the if fails to match a 404 will be returned
- $host and $args en $args_ are standard nginx variables see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables
- we add a ? ad the end of the rewrite to keep nginx from readding the url arguments

Comment: When I tried to put the top code into my config file and restart nginx, I got the following error


nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:347

with the other code, it just 404s when I go to /t/123

Comment: you MUST put the location blocks inside your server block, sounds like you're puttin it in your http block instead

Comment: Note: your server block is probably split out to a file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ or /etc/nginx/conf.d (depending on the distrution your using)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, this is what I (actually a friend) ended up doing:

```
   location / {
        root /home/jim/www;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
          rewrite ^/t/(.+)$ /ngu/short.php?t=$1 last;
          rewrite ^/u/(.+)$ /ngu/short.php?u=$1 last;
          rewrite ^/s/ /ngu/short.php last;
          break;
        }
    }
```

I don't understand it, but it works.